# load dll written in Rust from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rust, dll, dllexport

I am trying to write dynamic library and use it from Excel.
Now I can call my function from Excel, but it seems that the parameter to the function is passed in a wrong way.

My Rust code looks like below

```rust
use std::ffi::{c_char, CString};

use windows::core::{BSTR, PCSTR};
use windows::Win32::System::Com::{SAFEARRAY, VARIANT};
    
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::*;
use windows::s;


#[cfg(target_arch="x86_64")]
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "stdcall" fn pass_number(input: u32) -> u32 {
        
        let got = input.to_string();
        
        let c_string = CString::new("{}".replace("{}", &got)).unwrap();
        let ptr_str = CString::as_bytes_with_nul(&c_string);
        unsafe { MessageBoxA(None, PCSTR::from_raw(&(ptr_str[0]) as &u8 as *const u8), s!("pass_number()"), MB_OK); }

        input + 100
    }
```

And VBA code to load the dll

```vb
Public Declare PtrSafe Function add Lib "PATH_TO_DLL" _
Alias "pass_number" (ByVal num As Long) As Long

Sub test()
    MsgBox add(11)
End Sub
```

When I call `add()` from Excel worksheet, Windows messagebox pops up but the value of `got` is always 1 no matter parameter I pass to it. And if I execute VBA procedure, it raises a Run-time error '28', Out of stack space.

I tried different calling conventions like Win64, cdecl, and different integer data types for the parameter but the result was always the same.

From the fact that I can see the Windows message I guess that I can call the function from Excel but something goes wrong when parameter is passed to the function.

I am running the program on 64-bit machine and the library is compiled for this architecture using `cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.

Is there anybody who can let me know what is missing?

*More information

I tested with `i32` as input and output data type for `pass_number()` but nothing changed.
And `pass_number()` returns somehow when called via `add()` from Excel worksheet but the return value is always '101'. However when I changed the number 100 at the last line of Rust code to `new value`, the return value was changed to `new value + 1`.

Here is my Cargo.toml

```
[lib]
name="rustlib"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.48"
features = [
    "Data_Xml_Dom",
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_System_Com",
    "Win32_System_Ole",
    "Win32_Security",
    "Win32_System_Threading",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
    "Win32_System_WindowsProgramming",
    ]
    
[dependencies]
lazy_static = "*"
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
tokio = {version = "*", features = ["rt-multi-thread"]}
futures="*"
```

Comment: I think this is not the cause of the problem but Long is signed, u32 is unsigned, which may cause problems for negative numbers.

Comment: @z32a7ul This does not explain errors. The singed vs. unsigned issue may cause bugs and or unexpected results (but it will not result in outright failure) - The size is the same the only difference being that the first bit gets interpreted differently

Comment: If I were writing a dll for Excel I'd be using twinBasic, the up and coming drop in replacement for vbx.  I've tried and its an absolute doddle. https://twinbasic.com/preview.html

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII: Just as I said, "this is not the cause of the problem".

Comment: Please include your `Cargo.toml`

Comment: And are you sure that your version of Excel is 64-bit?

Comment: @PitaJ I included my Cargo.toml and my excel is 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

By installing 32-bit Excel and creating 32-bit dll, i could call the function in dll from Excel. But there is still a problem that passing pointer types (string, or array) from Excel to dll does not work well.